# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.a" is null

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, nullpointerexception

So I made this problem up and it's essentially the same problem I'm having at work. I have a dependency on an object and I don't have access to the source code for the getter. The field is an Integer but the getter returns an in. The worst part is that he initialized the Integer as null in the constructor. How do I serialize this so that it may return the object with the value a null?

```
public class TestObject {
    
    private Integer a;
    
    TestObject(){
        a = null;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    
    
}
```

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestObject a = new TestObject();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        try {
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(a));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class TestSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Integer tmpInt, 
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, 
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) 
                          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(tmpInt.toString());
    }
}
```

Error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.a" is null (through reference chain: TestObject["a"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:402)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:361)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:323)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:780)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:318)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4719)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3964)
at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.a" is null
at TestObject.getA(TestObject.java:11)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772)
... 6 more

Comment: Maybe you could serialize "null" integer to a special int value such as "0" and deserialize it back to "null".